# asp.net Treeview issue (can't get child nodes to display)

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have been working on this for a while, but cannot resolve the issue. I have searched S/O & Google, but no luck. Hoping someone on here can help resolve this.

I am not able to display the child nodes in my TreeView control. The data is being retrieved from a database.
The root node appears fine, but there are not child nodes displayed. How can I get the child nodes to be displayed?

My code is:

```
private void PopulateTreeNode(DataSet dsList)
{
    var treeNode = new TreeNode();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dsList.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if (dr["RecordTypeID"].ToString() == "1")
        {
            TreeNode NewNode = new TreeNode(dr["CustomerName"].ToString(), dr["customerID"].ToString());
            treeCustomer.Nodes.Add(NewNode);
        }
        else if (dr["RecordTypeID"].ToString() == "2")
        {
            TreeNode pNode = new TreeNode(dr["CustomerName"].ToString(), dr["customerID"].ToString());
            pNode.ChildNodes.Add(pNode);
        }
        else if (dr["RecordTypeID"].ToString() == "3")
        {
            TreeNode pNode = new TreeNode(dr["CustomerName"].ToString(), dr["customerID"].ToString());
            pNode.ChildNodes.Add(pNode);
        }
    }
    treeCustomer.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
    treeCustomer.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call treeCustomer.DataBind() if you are manually adding nodes like this. It is probably clearing out your tree.

Comment: Killing DataBind didn't help. Still only seeing the root node.

Comment: For RecordTypeID 2 and 3, you are creating a new TreeNode object, and adding it to its own child collection? It doesn't appear that you are adding to the treeCustomer or the treeNode objects. Is pNode.ChildNodes.Add(pNode); supposed to be treeCustomer.ChildNodes.Add(pNode); (or maybe looking up an existing node in the tree control and adding it there)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling treeCustomer.ExpandAll() ?

You may also need to set various properties of the treeview too; regarding displaying expand images etc..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding pNode to the child nodes of pNode.  This means it is never getting added to treeCustomer since only treeNode is being added to treeCustomer.  It should probably be added to the child nodes of treeNode, or possibly added as a node of treeNode.